# Post using HttpClient & Read HttpResponseMessage status

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am posting to an API using `HttpClient` and getting back the `HttpResponseMessage`.
I am reading the status code from the reply but I it's always `200`

**Posting:**

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(loginDto);
var stringContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:57770/api/Account/Login", stringContent);
```

I am replying from API the `HttpResponseMessage`:

```
return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
```

But when I read the `response`, it's always `200`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asp.Net Core no longer recognizes `HttpResponseMessage` as part of the pipeline. This means it will be treated like any other returned model and serialized as content. Hence the 200 OK status.

The API controller action should return `IActionResult` derived result.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SomeAction(...) {

    //...

    return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized); //401

    //...
}
```

Or just use

```
return Unauthorized();
```

which is derived from `StatusCodeResult` and is used a short hand to replace the code shown above.

Reference [ControllerBase.Unauthorized](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.unauthorized?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_Unauthorized).